# База не видит записи пока не переподключишься

Tags: php, mysql

Есть у меня вот такая цепочка событий

```
function foo()
{
    // делаю запрос на сторонний сервер, который делает запрос обратно на мой и записывает результат в базу
    $this->sendRequest('http://api.god/make-awesome');
    // проверяю наличие вновь созданной записи, но её нет. Но на самом деле она уже есть
    $res = $this->db->query('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `awesome` WHERE `maked` IS NULL')); // $res = false

    // а если сделать так, т.е. переподключиться к базе, то всё находит
    $this->db->close();
    $this->db->open();
    $res = $this->db->query('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `awesome` WHERE `maked` IS NULL')); // $res = true
}
```

Не пойму как заставить PHP видеть изменения в базе, сделанные параллельно другим процессом? Возможно ли это?

---

Ответ крылся в транзакции, на что любезно указал @AntonShchyrov

Comment: Что такое `db` и какой уровень изоляции транзакций используется?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov для чистоты эксперимента там просто функции mysqli_* без излишеств и транзакций

Comment: `SELECT @@autocommit` после `sendRequest` что возвращает?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , 0 вернул, всё-таки в транзакции дело?

Comment: действительно, не понимаю как оно так получилось, но добавил проверку на наличие активной транзакции.
спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас запущена транзакция. В InnoDB транзакция по умолчанию запускается с уровнем изоляции `REPEATABLE READ`, т.е. "повторяющееся чтение". При первом чтении делается снапшот данных и все последующие чтения происходят из этого снимка. Чтобы увидеть в такой транзакции данные, закоммиченные другой транзакцией нужно транзакцию перезапустить (вызвав commit или rollback)

Второй путь - поставить уровень изоляции `READ COMMITTED` тогда Ваша транзакция будет видеть данные, закоммиченные другой транзакцией после обычной повторной выборки.

Поменять уровень изоляции транзакции можно командой

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

или установив параметр

```
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
```

в конфиге MySQL сервера.

Третий путь, пожалуй самый неправильный, установить режим автокоммита и уйти от транзакций вообще

Подробнее об уровнях изоляции [здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)

Comment: второй путь, кажется мне наиболее логичным. Или есть какие-то подводные камни?

Comment: @j.Doe есть. 1) Если база на хостинге, то никто не даст Вам ковыряться в конфиге. 2) Логика приложения (в том числе и не Вашего) может быть построена на том, что два одинаковых запроса возвращают одинаковый результат (но за это нужно бить)

Comment: @j.Doe И самое главное - при смене уровня изоляции меняются алгоритмы блокировки

Comment: @j.Doe У себя я всегда после коннекта выполняю ряд запросов `SET TRANSACTION`, `SET NAMES` и не завишу от конфигов сервера вообще

Comment: это всё понятно. Меня больше интересует какой из режимов `REPEATABLE READ` или `READ COMMITTED` в целом даёт более ожидаемые результаты?

Comment: почитал документацию, всё прояснилось. спасибо